# Is there any way to restrict IAM users/Asumed Roles from enabling unauthenticated user identities in AWS cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

As an admin, I wanted my AWS users not to enable unauthenticated user identity in AWS Cognito. Is there any way to restrict this action? Can this be achieved through service control policy?

Basically I don't want my AWS users to enable AWS resource access to any guest users.

Comment: Do they still need to have permissions to create and edit cognito pools?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do anything but prevent them from creating Cognito resources entirely.

There is nothing in the [Cognito SAR pages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazoncognitoidentity.html) that indicates that you can differentiate on authenticated/unauthenticated identities.